# Send form info stored in a cookie with post using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm sending with Jquery a form but in certain cases, the form info is stored in a cookie with the data serialized and later I want to send the info reading from the cookie.

How can I send again that data from the cookie?

I'm using this 2 functions to work with the cookies. When sending the form using $.ajax I put the data as **'data: readCookie("cookiename")'**:

```
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
      var expires;

      if (days) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
          expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
      } else {
          expires = "";
      }
      document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
  }

  function readCookie(name) {
      var nameEQ = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
          if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return decodeURIComponent(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
      }
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: Make your coding easier with https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie BTW, why not read the cookie from server side instead of posting it?

Comment: what exactly are you asking? how to send it? or how to parse the data in the cookie?

Comment: If it is in a cookie...um,..it should be sent already as a cookie!

Comment: The info in the cookie is sent to another domain

Answer (score 0):

I did like this at the end to also include some extra values I had to also send in the POST:

```
var data_voto=JSON.parse(readCookie('votos'));


      for (var key in data_voto) {
         var obj = data_voto[key];
         var cont = 0;

         for (var prop in obj) {
            // important check that this is objects own property 
            // not from prototype prop inherited

            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
              if(cont==0){
                data_array.push({"name": obj.name, "value": obj.value});
                cont++;
              }else{
                cont = 0;
              }


            }
         }
      }
```